# Using dot notation with sum() to query the same, but multiple columns, in multiple databases

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite

There are multiple databases, one database for each time period (i.e. quarter). The column headers in each table are the same. Some of the columns. The data is identical between databases (e.g. ID, Name, Address, State, Website, etc). Some of the columns, the column header is the same but the 
data in the column is different between databases.
The goal is to: 
Select multiple columns from multiple databases, sum each column, convert the output from 000000000 to $000,000,000,000, adding three zero's to the output 
(currently the data is represented in 000's).

Following is an iteration of queries that work, ending in the queries that fail. 
Selecting one column from one database. This query works.

```
select  dep
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities;

output
"11005"
"34396"
"42244"
```

Adding a sum(columnName) method to this same query works.

```
select  sum(dep)
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities;

results: 3562807353
```

Attempting to sum(columnName) from multiple databases causes an error.

```
select  sum(dep)
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities, 
AllReports19930331AssetsAndLiabilities;

error: 
ambiguous column name: dep: select  sum(dep)
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities, 
AllReports19930331AssetsAndLiabilities;
```

Using dot notation to attach a database to a column. Query works.

```
select  AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities.dep
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities;


Output: 
"11005"
"34396"
"42244"
```

However when I attempt to include dot notation and add sum(columnName) to the query, it fails.

```
select  AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities.sum(dep)
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities;
```

I receive this error:

```
near "(": syntax error: select  AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities.sum(
```

**What are correct ways to write this query?**

The end goal is to select the same columns (e.g. col1, col2, col3, etc) from multiple databases (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4).
Sum each column, add three zero's the output, then convert from 000000000 to $000,000,000,000 
Note: There are 103 databases (i.e. one for each time period/quarter).

```
select  AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities.sum(dep), 
AllReports19930331AssetsAndLiabilities.sum(dep), 
AllReports19930630AssetsAndLiabilities.sum(dep)

From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities, 
AllReports19930331AssetsAndLiabilities, 
AllReports19930630AssetsAndLiabilities;
```

The above query outputs an error:

```
near "(": syntax error: select  AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities.sum(
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong :

```
select  sum(AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities.dep)
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use aliases!

```
select sum(aal.dep)
From AllReports19921231AssetsAndLiabilities aal;
```

The query is much easier to write and to read.  The table alias (whether the full table name or an abbreviation) is attached to the column name.  In SQL, this results in a *qualified column reference*.  The qualification specifies what table it is coming from.

The table alias is not attached to a function, because SQL does not currently allow tables to contain functions.